# Cannot get basic monodevelop/xamarin project to compile - "already has reference" error

Tags: asp.net, monodevelop, xamarin

I can't understand this at all. Have gone to monodevelop and downloaded xamarin studio and updated it to 4.0.3

I cannot get a clean compile of even a simple project. Either c# or vb.net.

"new" > "solution" > "asp.net" > "c#" > "web api"

"build"

17 errors. "the type or namespace name 'Object' could not be found". "The type or namespace 'EventArgs' could not be found". and so on.

If I use vb, I get errors relating to there already being a reference to assembly "system" in the project (I haven't added any other references).  If I delete all 4 files the project automatically adds then I get a clean compile but if I then add a web service file then I get errors saying "webmethod" can't be found (not surprising with system.web.services missing!)

I can't understand why a newly-installed program and default project just won't compile.  Windows 7 x64 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree - it is weird for a newly-installed program and default project to do that.

The solution for me was to add `using System;` in the problematic *.cs files (Default.aspx.cs that is for me, since I deleted automatically generated Global.asax and Global.asax.cs files).

Comment: Yes, thanks. I forgot to update - someone answered me with a similar thing on the xamarin forum.  It's pretty poor to be honest that xamarin doesn't add the basics at create time. It basically creates a project out of the box that won't compile!